# How can i get the currently selected number of row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hello and thanks for helping me.

How can i get the currently selected row of my table?
I need the number of this selected row, because i want to send it to the server

Look at this live example:

```
 http://live.datatables.net/qexevaj/7/edit
```

If i select a row and click on the button above the table the alert says ' Object object'.
How can i solve this?

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: although it's impossible to help you without seeing some code, it would probably be better to post some data (e.g. id of the item in the row) rather than the row number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#button').click( function () {
        alert($("#example tr.selected").index());
        alert($("#example tr.selected td:first-child").html());
 });
```

it will alert index started from 0.
<kbd>[live demo](http://live.datatables.net/qexevaj/16/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks that was the solution;)

Comment: One question at last..how can i get the name from the column 'name' of the currently selected row?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) like,

```
var na = table.row('.selected').index();
```

See [Demo](http://live.datatables.net/qexevaj/14/edit)